# SetLabel method of jqGrid along with setGroupHeaders

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to use `setlabel` method of jqGrid along with `setGroupHeaders`. It does not work. But when I remove this `setGroupHeaders`, `setLabel` method works and I am able to change my column headers dynamically. Is there anyway to use both of the methods together?

Adding the code fragment

```js
$("#aGrid").jqGrid({
    shrinkToFit: false,
    autowidth: true,
    height: 305,    
    colNames: ['Parameter','T0','T1','T2','T3'],
    colModel: [
        {name:"paramName",index:"paramName",width:115,sortable:false,frozen:true},
        {name:"t0",index:"t0",cellattr:myFormatter,hidden:false},
        {name:"t1",index:"t1",cellattr:myFormatter,hidden:false},
        {name:"t2",index:"t2",cellattr:myFormatter,hidden:false},
        {name:"t3",index:"t3",cellattr:myFormatter,hidden:false}
    ],
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    sortable: false,
    caption: "A Grid" 
});

$("#aGrid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
    useColSpanStyle: true,                    
    groupHeaders: [
        {startColumnName:'t0',
         numberOfColumns:8,
         titleText:'10.152.141.142'}]
});

$.ajax({
    type : "get",
    url : url,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success :  function(responseText){
        for(var i=0;i<=responseText.length;i++)
            {
            if(i === 0){
                var newColHeaders = responseText[i];
                $("#aGrid").jqGrid('setLabel', "t0",newColHeaders['t0']);
                $("#aGrid").jqGrid('setLabel', "t1",newColHeaders['t1']);
                $("#aGrid").jqGrid('setLabel', "t2",newColHeaders['t2']);
                $("#aGrid").jqGrid('setLabel', 't3',newColHeaders['t3']);

            }else{
                $("#aGrid").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,responseText[i]);
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError){

    }
});
```

If I use the same code after removing `setGroupHeaders` call in above code, column headers change works as expected.

Comment: could you post code fragments which your attempts?

Comment: Below is the code fragment

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any code. You should click on "edit" button below your question and modify/append the text of your question. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) you can read tips how to format the code in the editor.

Comment: Hi Oleg. I have editted the question now. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because of your group header.
When you want to change the header, first destroy the group header and then call the setLabel and again reconstruct the group Header.

```
        $("#aGrid").jqGrid('destroyGroupHeader');
```

//Now change the Label of header

```
        $("#aGrid").jqGrid('setLabel', "to","ABC"); //colModel name value

        constructGroupHeader();
```

Construct group Header should be like this

```
    function constructGroupHeader()
    {
jQuery("#aGrid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
    useColSpanStyle: true,                    
    groupHeaders: [
        {startColumnName:'t0',
         numberOfColumns:8,
         titleText:'10.152.141.142'}]
});
        }
```

Hope this helps.